# ¿Como puedo imprimir una lista de listas por filas donde en la primera línea se encuentren los primeros elementos de cada sublista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por ejemplo tengo la lista :

```
ejemplo = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Deseo imprimir en el siguiente orden:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

o explicado de otra forma; cada lista debe imprimirse de manera vertical una al lado de la otra.

Answer (score 4):

Además de usar bucles "explícitos", podemos usar características de **programación funcional** de python, que hace los bucles "invisibles", pues operamos directamente con las listas. En concreto voy a usar:

- `zip()`. Esta función recibe varias listas como parámetros y devuelve un iterador. Al iterar sobre él, obtenemos en cada iteración una tupla formada por los elementos que están en la misma posición en cada una de las listas. Por ejemplo, si hago `zip([1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,8,4])` la primera iteración devolvería `(1,2,3)`, la siguiente `(4.5.6)`, etc. Es decir justo lo que necesitamos.

  El único problema es que las listas que le queremos pasar a `zip()` no están separadas, sino en una sola variable `ejemplo`. Pero podemos usar el operador `*` de desempaquetado así:  `zip(*ejemplo)`. Ese operador convierte cada elemento de la lista `ejemplo` en un argumento separado para `zip()`, que recibiría entonces lo tres argumentos antes vistos.
- `map()` esta función permite aplicar otra función que le indiquemos como primer parámetro a cada elemento de un iterable que le especifiquemos como segundo parámetro. El resultado es otro iterable con los resultados de aplicar la función a cada elemento. Lo usaré para convertir a `str` cada elemento de las tuplas `(1,2,3)` etc.
- `str.join()` permite concatenar una serie de cadenas en una sola, usando como separador el que pongamos en `str`. Esto lo usaré para crear cada una de las líneas de salida, juntando las cadenas retornadas por `map()`  y separándolas con espacios.

Aunque la explicación ha sido larga, el código es muy breve:

```
for trio in zip(*ejemplo):
  print(" ".join(map(str, trio)))
```

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Si queremos llevar al límite la idea de no usar bucles explícitos, podemos reemplazar el `for` que sirve para imprimir cada línea por otro `str.join()` que concatene las líneas usando `\n` como separador. Aún así hará falta una *list comprehension* para iterar sobre cada tupla y convertirla en una línea de la salida, por lo que seguimos teniendo un `for`, dentro de esa comprensión.

El resultado es altamente ilegible y por tanto no recomendable, pero lo dejo ahi para los fanáticos de la programación funcional y del los *programas de una línea*:

```
print("\n".join(" ".join(map(str, p)) for p in zip(*ejemplo)))
```

Answer (score 1):

lo puedes hacer con 2 ciclo for (anidados) de la siguiente forma;

```
ejemplo = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
for i in range(len(ejemplo[0])):
     for j in range(len(ejemplo)):
         print(ejemplo[j][i], end="")
     print("")
```

Esto te debe funcionar para python 3.x, el `end=""` sirve simplemente para indicar que no se haga un salto de linea, es decir, se reemplaza el salto por  "" (nada). Espero te sirva, saludos.